# problems with cMath and the sin function

Tags: c++, type-conversion, cmath, trigonometry

Hey so i'm doing some graphics math and inserting what i believe to be a float (**i'm pretty sure the ways i manipulate the float beforehand is messing something up somehow**...) into the function and getting strange, negative results back.

for instance when doing the following opperations when Angle initially equals 350.0, test ends up being
-.99. **Why?**

```
Angle= (float)(Angle-(int)Angle)+(float)((int)Angle%90); 

// calculates x and y based on angle and Hypotenuse
float test= sin(Angle);
float test2= 1/(Speed*Time);
float test3= test/test2;
buffX= sin(Angle)/ (1.f/(Speed*Time));
buffY= sin(Angle-90)/ (1.f/(Speed*Time));
```

trying to keep Angle a float by putting (float) before everything didn't work... please help! **Thanks!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because the C/C++ runtime function `sin()` expects the argument in radians, not degrees.

Convert to radians with:

```
float test= sin(Angle / 180 * M_PI);
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

sin takes its arguments in radians, not degrees. You need to take you number and multiply it pi/180

Comment: For best accuracy, start with modulo reduction, then resolve the value to an octant, then convert an angle from 0 to 45 degrees into 0 to pi/2 radians.  Otherwise some math libraries may report that the sine of 180 degrees isn't exactly zero [and possibly go so far as to waste time trying to compute exactly how far it is from zero].